# How do I access the Service Connection configuration within an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML Pipeline and I have a verified Service Connection which is allowed to be used on all pipelines.

How do I select which Service Connection is to be used for a particular YAML Pipeline, and how within that Pipeline do I retrieve the Service Connection values in order to use it?

I know that various YAML templates accept a Service Connection identifier which I can select while configuring those tasks, but I have some tasks which require me to configure a CLI tool with the Service Connection credentials and I don't see how to do that.

In the entire Azure DevOps documentation [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-using-automated-security) is the only thing I've found relating to this question. Which is really not helpful.

```
4. After the new service connection is created:

    If you're using the classic editor, select the connection name you assigned in the Azure subscription setting of your pipeline.
    If you're using YAML, copy the connection name into your code as the azureSubscription value.
```

Comment: What type of service connection? If it's an Azure service connection, you can run CLI commands in an Azure CLI step which will authenticate to Azure for you.

Comment: It's an Azure service connection. I know I can run CLI commands using the AzureCLI task. But I want to get the authentication createntials from the service connection so that I can use them directly. E.g. for authentication within a C# script using the Azure SDK

Comment: Once you're logged in, tools like the Azure CLI and the C# client libraries can retrieve the credentials from the cache.